# Can I use exterior paint over interior paint+primer?

Tags: paint, exterior, interior, primer, acrylic

Can I use an interior paint+primer as the primer/undercoat for an exterior paint?

I have an unfinished exterior wood door that I want to paint before installation.

I have some interior paint+primer that was used on my interior trim. I have some exterior paint that was used on the exterior trim. The interior is [Valspar](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Valspar-Signature-Ultra-White-Base-A-Satin-Tintable-Interior-Paint-Actual-Net-Contents-124-fl-oz/999989904), the exterior is [Dunn-Edwards Evershield](https://www.dunnedwards.com/products/exterior-paints-and-primers/finishes/evershield). I'm pretty sure both are 100% acrylic-latex paint. Both are semi-gloss.

My plan is to paint the entire door with the interior paint+primer. Once I've applied a few coats and it has thoroughly dried, I'll then paint the exterior facing side with the exterior paint.

Will I run into any issues painting exterior paint over the interior paint+primer?

Comment: I'll let the experts answer. But my hunch is: As long as it is the same general type of paint - oil vs. latex - it shouldn't matter much. Exterior vs. interior is (I think) the same stuff, perhaps more additives in the exterior to help with UV, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I was kinda thinking the same thing but I've had some paint mishaps in the past and wanted to confirm just in case.

Comment: Meh, paint+primer. That’s not really a thing.  They are different jobs.  If you want  it to last, use a proper alkyd primer for wood.